# can't enable Net Zero Cloud on my developer edition org

Tags: trailhead, developer-org, cloud

I was doing trailheads about setting up a net zero cloud but on the setup I can't find "Net Zero" there. It doesn't even appear on the Permission Set License Assignments.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.netzero_setup_enable_automation.htm&type=5),  Net Zero Cloud is paid product and this won't be available by default. You would need '**Net Zero Cloud Manager**' permission set license to enable Net zero cloud in your org.

If you do not see Net Zero Cloud permission set license reach out to your account executive. However, you can signup [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/sustainability/net-zero-cloud-free-trial/?d=cta-footer-226) for free 30 days trial of Net Zero Cloud.

See pricing details of Net Zero Cloud [here](https://www.salesforce.com/products/net-zero-cloud/pricing/).